# Horizontal scroll appears at lower resolution- Responsive issue

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have strange problem with website responsiveness.
When on desktop resolution no horizontal scroll appears at Chrome.
When i resize it to lower resolutions 400px width and less the  horizontal scroll appears.
I think some element is forcing width bigger than actuall screen size but i cant find it! 
Please help.
Here is website [link](http://analogevents.pejinsystems.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code,

You have to get rid of this code in your footer styles. Your `margin-right` is making your content overflow.

Try using padding, or something similar instead.

It appears you are using bootstrap for that.. So the best way to do this would be to overwrite this by creating a

```
#footer > div.row {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
 }
```

or if you have bootstrap locally then you can probably delete from there. But i just overwrite it using `!impornat

```
.row {
/* margin-right: -15px; */
margin-left: -15px;
}
```